# What does set.seed(any number) command means?

Tags: random, command-line, r

I am currently studying R. While studying that I came across a command **set.seed(any number)** . After googling also I didn't understood much except that it has something to do with **Random number generation**.

But I am not familiar with the concept of Random number generation. So, can someone please explain this command to me?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-random number generators work by taking the previous pseudo-random number, and applying a "magic" function which scrambles it to produce a new number that *appears to be* completely unrelated to the previous one.  Just keep repeating the process for each new random number you want.

But you need a starting number to kick the whole process off.  That's the seed.  If you always use the same seed, you always get the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers.  This is sometimes useful (e.g. when debugging), but often not good.  If you want different numbers each time, use different seeds.  Perhaps use the current time of day as the seed.